# Trying to get the id of a file, outputs an error

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a folder and inside two spreadsheets. I can open the folder but when I try to get the id of the files inside I get this:

Im getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot find function getId in object function getOwner()
>   {/* */}. (line 13, file "Código")

This is the code:

```
function onOpen(){
   // This active sheet.
   var mainSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   // To store all of the invoice data
   var invoiceData = [];

  DocsList.getFileById("0AiF3_xmQCMztdE56YlNyLTJlS1l3YTlVN2xpd2ZodVE");
   // Get all files inside a drive folder
   var files = DocsList.getFolderById("0ByF3_xmQCMztWlBOdDBIdF9EbjA");
   // For each file in the folder
   for (var i in files) {

      files[i].getId(); // THIS IS LINE 13.
     //echo(files[i]);

      // Open the current spreadsheet in the iteration
      var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(files[i].getId());
      // Get the contents as an array and add it to invoiceData
      invoiceData.push(thisSpreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues());
   }
   // Clear all content in active sheet
   mainSpreadsheet.getDataRange.clearContent();
   // Get the write range from the number of values inside invoiceData
   var writeRange = mainSpreadsheet.getRange(1,1,invoiceData.length, invoiceData[0].length)
   // Add the data to the spreadsheet. 
   writeRange.setValues(invoiceData);
}
```

Since the folder is shared, the files are also shared.

Comment: DocList service is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to get the Id of the files which is actual equal to the folder Id.

I've cleaned up your functions a little bit. You should be able to figure out the rest :)

```
function onOpen(){
    // This active sheet.
    var mainSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    // To store all of the invoice data
    var invoiceData = [];

    // Get folder
    var folder = DocsList.getFolderById("0Bw-qu6vryQOtSzJqOS1mbmhQMUE");

    // Get files in that folder
    var files = folder.getFiles();

    // Iterate through the files  
    for(var i in files){

        // Get each file id
        var names = files[i].getId();

        // Open the file in iteration
        var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(names);

        //Push the data from the spreadsheet into the invoiceData array.
        invoiceData.push(thisSpreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues());
    }

    // Clear all content in active sheet
    mainSpreadsheet.getDataRange.clearContent();

    // Get the write range from the numbe of values inside invoiceData
    var writeRange = mainSpreadsheet.getRange(1,1,invoiceData.length, invoiceData[0].length);

    // Add the data to the spreadsheet
    writeRange.setValues(invoiceData);

}
```